# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLParagraphElement> has no method 'click' works in FF fails in chrome.. how to fix?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, jquery-events

I'm building a custom autocomplete for a search box on our site.

I've coded a `keyup` event handler to handle keyboard input for scrolling through the autocomplete list, having enter select elements/submit form, etc...

The problem I am having is I want an enter `keypress` to act as a the equivalent of a click on the element.  However when the enter `keypress` calls the click method bound to the `<p>` tag, in Chrome, the click event handler can't be found. In Firefox it works just fine.

Am I not allowed to bind click event listeners to `<p>` tags in Chrome? What's going on? This works perfectly in Firefox.

Here is relevant code for the concrete examples:

I've bound the click event via jQuery's live method to all list elements that are appended to my list during the autocomplete like so:

```
$('.suggestion .section li p').live( 'click',  function (){ 
        
        debugLog("a p tag was clicked");
        
        $("#search-input").data('skip-hide', true);
        $("#search .suggestion").data('selected-index', -1) ;
        
        $("#search-input").val($(this).parent().data('search-text'));
        $("#search-input").closest("form").submit();

    });
```

Then a bit later I do this:

```
$("#search-input").keyup(function(event){
    
    switch(event.keyCode )
    {
        case 13:
        if($("#search .suggestion").data('selected-index') != undefined){
            debugLog('a defined index was set when enter was pressed');

//THIS IS THE FAILING LINE IN CHROME
            $("#search .suggestion li p")[$("#search .suggestion").data('selected-index')].click();
            return false;
        }
```

The html snippet that my autocompete fills out looks like this:

```
<form id="search-form" action="<?php echo $this->baseUrl(); ?>/search" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8">
            <div id="search">
                <input id="search-input" type="text" class="input-box input-focus" name="q" value="Enter a product or store..." /><input type="image" id="search-form-image" src="/images/nav-btn-search.gif" />
                
                <div class="suggestion" style="display:none;">
                    <div class="section" id="stores-autocomplete">
                        <strong>Stores</strong> 
                        <ul>
                        </ul>  
                    </div>
                    <div class="section" id="searches-autocomplete">
                        <strong>Searches</strong>
                        <ul>
                        
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="section lastChild" id="coupons-autocomplete">
                        <strong>Coupons</strong>
                        <ul>
                           
                        </ul>  
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.eq()` instead of `[]` to select the paragraph. Then, invoke `.click()` (as a jQuery method):

```
$("#search .suggestion li p").eq($("#search .suggestion").data('selected-index')).click()
```

When using square braces, you're selecting a DOM element, and trying to invoke the DOM `.click` method. The solution involves using `.eq()`, so that a jQuery object is selected, so that jQuery's `.click()`, aka `.trigger('click')`, method can be invoked.